# Not able to read a file from other package in the same module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I am using Intellij Idea - 2021.2.4 and Java 8.
In Intellij, I am not able to read a file in another package in the same module.  The file is under main and not resource folder. But in Eclipse, I am able to read.

For example.  Below code prints different outputs in both eclipse and intellij.

```
import java.net.URL;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL resource = TestMain.class.getResource("/org/files/input.txt");
        if(resource == null) {
            System.out.println("Resource is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Resource found!!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In Intellij, the code prints "Resource is null", but in eclipse, the code prints "Resource found!!".

Is there any setting I need to enable/disable in intellij ? Why code is behaving different in Intellij Idea ?

Comment: This works for me in Intellij IDEA. By the way src/main/resources/org/files/input.txt would be a better place to put your file.

Comment: I understand we need to put the file file under resource. But for some reason, I need to read a file from the other package.  The same project structure is printing "Resource Found!!" for you ? or you placed a file under resource and ran ?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. You're certain your code is exactly the same? If you missed the leading `/` it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes its same.. I am trying in different machine now and report

Comment: It didnt work for me in different machine as well. Same result. @tgdavies